# PowerShell script not pulling files from directory

Tags: powershell, copy, directory

I am writing a script to copy user data from remote computers (\RemotePC\C$\Users*). Files considered relevant are within 90 days for my scenario.  The problem I am having is that no matter what I seem to change, the folders never seem to copy. From the example, my C:\TestFolder\ contains 4 folders with a text file and a text file by itself.

When I run my script, only the text file by itself gets copied.  I want EVERYTHING in this directory to be copied.  Thanks in advance.

```
 $OldPC = l02argallim
#$OldPC = Read-Host "Input PC name to copy files from"
#$OldPath = "\\OldPC\C$\Users\*"
$OldPath = "C:\TestFolder\"
$NewPath = "C:\OldUserBackup\"
$MaxDays = "-1"
$CurrDate = Get-Date
#$Exclude = @("rgallimore", "eaune", "dfreeman", "pduffee", "public", "default", "administrator")
$Exclude = @("b")
cls
$PathExist = Test-Path -Path $NewPath
    if($PathExist -eq $True)
    {
        Write-Host "$NewPath has already been created." -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "The script will now terminate." -ForegroundColor Red
        Pause        
    }
    elseif($PathExist -eq $False)
    {
        New-Item $NewPath -type directory
        foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $OldPath))
        {   
            if($file.LastWriteTime -gt ($CurrDate).AddDays($MaxDays))            
            {
                Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $NewPath -Recurse -Force
                Write-Host "$file copied successfully." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            }
            else
            {
            Write-Host "Not copying $file" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
        }
        $a = [math]::abs($MaxDays)
        Write-Host "$OldPath successfully copied contents from the past $a day(s) to $NewPath" -ForegroundColor Green
        Pause           
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "An unknown error has occured. Error 01." -ForegroundColor Cyan
        Pause
    }
```

Comment: Why are you exiting in the code that does the Copy-Item?  Seems like you are exiting out of the loop prematurely.

Comment: I have revised (see original post) and now my only problem is it isn't copying the first folder in the directory. I think it may be because it's an array and starting at 1 instead of 0 or something like that.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code using the Powershell IDE?  That should show what the problem is.

Comment: Admittedly this is my first real PS script although I have a few years of Java experience.  How can I see what the variable is holding after the "foreach" statement? I think my issues have something to do with an array starting at an improper point.

Comment: You should run the code in the Powershell ISE.  You can set breakpoints and inspect variables.

Comment: @Maverick94 And it's not just because `(Get-ChildItem $OldPath)[0].LastWriteTime` is more than 1 day old?

Comment: I fixed it! It was simply a logic error. The first folder was being copied before the new directory was created. I simply made the directory before the loop.

Comment: @rrirower I finally have it fixed. Now I need it to exclude some folders.  I have googled and found a few examples, but my codes doesn't work with the same logic.  Any idea where to put an exclude in my code?

Comment: @Maverick94 How about adding something like this just inside your foreach?  `if ($file.name -in $Exclude) {continue}`  If you have the same format for the `$file` as the format of the entries in `$Exclude` (i.e.  just file/folder names only) the -in operator should find the entry in the exclude array once you uncomment it.